# How do you force Webpack to ignore errors in URL resolution in the build process?

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader, extract-text-plugin

My directory structure is as follows:

```
example/
├── css/
│     ├── styles.css
├── img/
│     ├── background.jpg
└── src/
    ├── scss/
    │   ├── app.scss
    └── app.js
```

When I specify an absolute URL for a background image in `app.scss`, such as `background-image: url("/img/background.jpg");`, it will work just fine.

However, if I specify a relative URL, such as `background-image: url("../img/background.jpg");`, the build process will fail.

Is there a way to force Webpack to ignore such errors?

If it would just proceed to build my `styles.css` file, it would of course properly load the background via the relative URL, but I just can't ever get it that far.

It is important to resolve this because otherwise you are forced to deploy websites into the webroot and cannot use subdirectories as the absolute URL would break on production.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't make sense to ignore file resolution errors in webpack and i don't think there is a way to do it.

but from your app structure, the relative path should `../../img/background.jpg`

**Update:**

sorry got that wrong at the beginning, I was able to reproduce your issue with sass and `sass-loader`, turned out it's a common issue and there is a [section](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#problems-with-url) for it in `sass-loader`, and they mentioned 2 solutions:

> - Add the missing url rewriting using the resolve-url-loader. Place it before the sass-loader in the loader chain.
> - Library authors usually provide a variable to modify the asset path. bootstrap-sass for example has an $icon-font-path